# how to use router-link custom navigation instead of `to` prop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

```
<router-link to="/"  tag="a" :title="title">
            <span class="icon icon-home i-large" />
            <span class="class-2">Name</span>
        </router-link>
```

This is what I have...

As you can see , I am using `to` prop. But I don't want to use it. Whenever someone clicks on this, i want to execute a function and use programatic navigation.

How is this possible? the structure and htmls that I have shouldn't change and it still should work as expected.

Comment: I think you could do that all inline if you wrote like so: `:to="myFuncRetVal"` and added `@click="myFunc"` as long as your func returns a string.

Comment: `to` is a `prop`, so you can do anything that you can do with a  `prop`. I added an answer with two snippets: one uses a `computed` value to change this prop, the second adds a `method` to change the value of this prop.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this you mean?

```
<a @click="functionThatExecutesMyCode">
  <span class="icon icon-home i-large" />
  <span class="class-2">Name</span>
</a>

functionThatExecutesMyCode() {
   this.$router.push({ to: 'newRoute'})
}
```

Else you should use the navigation guards: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html

Comment: I still want to have `router-link` , but i can't add `click` event on it and remove `to` prop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to change `:to props` to add a function, because it is predefined as only accept a string in its docs. https://router.vuejs.org/api/#to

However, I suggest another way to implement what you want, you can add the logic in `beforeEach` hook. For example

```
router.beforeEach( (to, from, next) => {

  // implement your logic here, for example if no internet, go to error page

  if (!navigator.onLine && to.name !== "NetworkError") {
    next({ name: "NetworkError" });
    return false;
   }
  next();
}
```

For more info, look at their docs: https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-beforeeach

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you exactly want.

There are easier solutions, like:

```js
const Root = {
  template: '<div>Root</div>'
}
const Route1 = {
  template: '<div>Route1</div>'
}

const routes = [{
    path: '/',
    name: 'root',
    component: Root
  },
  {
    path: '/1',
    name: 'route1',
    component: Route1
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes // short for `routes: routes`
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router,
  data: {
    selected: 'root',
    options: ['root', 'route1']
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="(option, i) in options">
      {{ option }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <router-view></router-view>
  <router-link :to="{ name: selected }">{{ selected }}</router-link>
</div>
```

In this solution I used a `named route`, and the "name" can be changed by the select input.

The next solution is to incorporate a function:

```js
const Root = {
  template: '<div>Root</div>'
}
const Route1 = {
  template: '<div>Route1</div>'
}

const routes = [{
    path: '/',
    name: 'root',
    component: Root
  },
  {
    path: '/1',
    name: 'route1',
    component: Route1
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes // short for `routes: routes`
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router,
  data: {
    selected: 'root',
    options: ['root', 'route1']
  },
  methods: {
    changeRouteName() {
      return this.selected
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="(option, i) in options">
      {{ option }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <router-view></router-view>
  <router-link :to="{ name: changeRouteName() }">{{ selected }}</router-link>
</div>
```

By adding a `method` to resolve the `name` of the component, it's possible to build ANY logic on the `to` of the `<router-link`. You could also use `path` instead of `name` of course - I just like named components.

It does not remove the `click` event from the `to` prop, but you can do your logic before returning the `name` it's "waiting" for.